# Receiving and handling media messages in Twilio-dialogflow WhatsApp integration

Tags: twilio

I have deployed a server on GCP to receive message traffic from twilio via webhook and integrated it with Google's dialogflow. You can see the original project here "https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations#readme".

The function works fine for receiving and responding via intent detection but it can't handle any media inputs from a user as dialogflow can't interpret it. I've been trying to code a simple IF statement that converts any input media into URL's prior to processing by dialogflow. The full code server.js file is given below:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const app = express();
const dialogflowSessionClient = require('../botlib/dialogflow_session_client.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const projectId = 'PROJECT-ID';
const phoneNumber = "+1##########";
const accountSid = '*********************';
const authToken = '*******************';

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const sessionClient = new dialogflowSessionClient(projectId);

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
   console.log('listner marker');
   console.log('Your Twilio01 integration server is listening on port '+ listener.address().port); 
});

app.post('/', async function(req, res) {
   const body = req.body;
   const text = body.Body;
   const id = body.From;
   console.log('body marker');
   const dialogflowResponse = (await sessionClient.detectIntent(text, id, body)).fulfillmentText;
   const twiml = new  MessagingResponse();
   const message = twiml.message(dialogflowResponse);
   res.send(twiml.toString());});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
   listener.close(() => {
   console.log('Closing http server.');
   process.exit(0);
});
});
```

I have tried to add my IF statement like below but it fails to execute when placed into the main file.

```
if (MessagingResponse.NumMedia != "0") {
    console.log(MessagingResponse.MediaUrl0);
    MessagingResponse = MessagingResponse.MediaUrl0;
    console.log(response.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot change the **const** variable value on the next statement so

change your

```
const text;
```

to

```
 var text;
```

and add

```
if(body.MediaUrl0){
    text = body.MediaUrl0;
  }
```

before

```
const dialogflowResponse = (await sessionClient.detectIntent(
  text, id, body)).fulfillmentText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're trying to read the `NumMedia` and other properties from the `MessagingResponse` class. You should be trying to read it from the body of the incoming request: `req.body.NumMedia`.

**Edit**

Checked your code from the repo. The `const` still doesn't seem right. Try this:

```js
app.post("/", async function (req, res) {
  const body = req.body;
  let text;
  if (body.NumMedia != "0") {
    text = body.MediaUrl0;
  } else {
    text = body.Body;
  }
  const id = body.From;
  const dialogflowResponse = (await sessionClient.detectIntent(text, id, body))
    .fulfillmentText;
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message(dialogflowResponse);
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

In this case we define `text` with `let` instead of `const` and outside of the conditional. That way we can reassign to `text` and use it later in the function too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I added this code but its still not working. Any guidance on this . 
<br>
'    app.post('/', async function(req, res) {

     if (req.body.NumMedia != "0"){
     const imageurl = req.body.MediaUrl0;
      const body = imageurl;
    } else {
     const body = req.body;
    }'

Comment: Not sure what you’re saying there. Is that working for you? I’m guessing it doesn’t, but only because you are declaring `const` within the two conditional blocks so it isn’t available in the rest of the scope of the function.

Comment: You're right and I declared the constants appropriately now. However, still no luck. I have created a Git repository with the entire code. You can see the whole code in action there and if you'd like I can add you to the rep for contribution. I intend to keep it public. 
https://github.com/Adnanhhk/dialogflow-media-twilio-integration/blob/main/twilio/server.js

Comment: Updated my answer, take a look and see if that works for you.